# Testing convergence of the series $\sum \frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I have a series as follows:-
$$\sum \frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$
I am to test the convergence of this series for natural numbers $n>0$

My approach :-
$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}<\frac{1}{n^3} \Rightarrow\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}<\frac{2n}{n^3}$$
Now since$\sum\frac{2}{n^2}$converges ,the series under consideration converges.
Is it right or wrong?

Comment: It's right. ${}$

Comment: See [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: @Lucian This is 1. more sophisticated, 2. not necessary, 3. distracting the OP from the question they are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works. You are simply using the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with upper bound $\frac{2}{n^2}$ and lower bound $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, we get

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2-1/n}{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)} = 2$ , which is non zero and finte and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $ is convergent by $p$ test,  Thus  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $  and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converge togeather.